# How to check if locations are within my circle region?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, geoserver

I can use GPS to get my current location, I'd like to retrieve all the POIs which within my circle region.

1. The center point of circle is my current location, radius of circle region is x.
2. POI item is stored in database with its location and other information.

Which solution is the best way to retrieve all the POIs which within my circle.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: Using what provider?  You need a webservice that will provide you with that data.  There's multiple providers out there, each with different TOS, costs, and rate limits.  We can't really pick one for you.

Comment: (Maybe not suitable in your sitution) But I recommend mongoDB to store all the POIs. Then you can retrieve easily what you want cause there is geo query..

Comment: You do not need a webservise for this

Comment: I don't think I have a idea can retrieve those POIs which within circle region with one query. if yes, can you please give me a schema that how to store my POI in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you've retrieved all of your location points, retrieved your location using [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and wish to check which of those lie inside of your circle area, this may be one way to achieve your goal:

```
int RADIUS;
ArrayList<Point> points;
Location myLocation;
for(Point point : points){
    Location pointLocation = Location("");
    pointLocation.setLatitude(point.x);    // assume x values are latitudes
    pointLocation.setLongitude(point.y);    // assume y values are longitudes
    if(myLocation.distanceTo(Location pointLocation) < RADIUS){
        // This point lies inside
    }
}
```

Another, less Android-ish way would be to check if your data points satisfy the equation:

```
(myLocation.getLatitude() - pointLocation.getLatitude()) ^ 2 + (myLocation.getLongitude()) - pointLocation.getLongitude()) ^ 2 <= RADIUS ^ 2
```

Since this equation presupposes that the Earth surface is flat, the result would contain error, magnitude of which would grow with the RADIUS value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't want to retrieve all the points from server. It would be very expensive if I have a lot of data in my database. I just want to retrieve the points which with my circle. I think it should be common question like redfin finding homes around you.

Comment: Ok, I see. You do understand that you still have to perform the comparison (which may also happen on server-side, may also be a prepackaged solution), right? I suggest that you add more info on your server-side implementation, since it is not really an android question

Comment: Yes, I think this is also a server question. I'm curious how redfin retrieve all the POIs which within the region user selected. I think they also have this issue.